# Is the projection $p: X\times_Z Y\to Y$ also an immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Z$ be an immersion of schemes and $g: Y\to Z$ is any morphism of schemes, is the projection $p: X\times_Z Y\to Y$ also an immersion?

Comment: Yes it is true. This is known as "immersions are stable under base extension".